# AWS CodeBuild failing when building docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I'm trying to setup my codebuild pipeline using [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html). Everything goes fine to the moment when CodeBuild starts building docker image with this command

```
docker build -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
```

When processing this command AWS is throwing this error

```
Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker build -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .. Reason: exit status 125
```

ENV variables are set using CodeBuild and locally image building is working with the same command.

My buildspec file

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - IMAGE_TAG=$IMAGE_TAG
      - IMAGE_REPO_NAME=$IMAGE_REPO_NAME          
      - docker build -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
      - docker tag "$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG" "$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG"      
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
```

Comment: Where is the `$IMAGE_TAG` defined?

Comment: Inside environment section in CodeBuild project config.

Comment: OK, just wanted to check if it wasn't the reason for the command to fail. Have you tried building the image locally maybe?

Comment: Yes, locally is working.

Comment: Is the CodeBuild project running in `PrivilegedMode`?

Comment: Yes, the PrivilegedMode is enabled.